# Ways of applying a function over rows of data frame using 'apply' and the row index as argument for the applied function

Tags: r, apply

Here is a working case relevant to my issue:

```
# build a sample data frame
r1 <- c("XX","FV","U1","U2","U1")
r2 <- c("U1","U2","U1","U2","U2")
r3 <- c("XX","U2","XX","U2","U2")
test.df <- as.data.frame(rbind(r1,r2,r3))
# build the desired function. This function will return a result based on the evaluation of a given condition
# what the function does is not that important, just of note is that requires two arguments that will be sent from 'apply' function (edited comment)
fun.Majority <- function(my.row1, initial.value) {
  ifelse ((sum(grepl("U1", my.row1))==2) & (sum(grepl("U2", my.row1))==2), result <- "U1", result <- initial.value)
  return(result)
}
# create a new data frame with the first column containing the indices of the rows
test.df.idx <- cbind(1:nrow(test.df), test.df)
test.df.idx
#    1:nrow(test.df) V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# r1               1 XX FV U1 U2 U1
# r2               2 U1 U2 U1 U2 U2
# r3               3 XX U2 XX U2 U2

# use apply on test.df.idx calling the fun.Majority. 
test.df$Mj <- apply(test.df.idx, MARGIN=1, function(my.row) fun.Majority(my.row[c(-1,-5)], as.character(test.df.idx[as.numeric(my.row[1]),6])))
# This is the relevant line to my issue. 
# Is there another way to pass the row index to my function without calling it from the test.df.idx as my.row[1]? 
# Is 'apply' allowing such operation?

# here is the final output
test.df
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 Mj
# r1 XX FV U1 U2 U1 U1
# r2 U1 U2 U1 U2 U2 U1
# r3 XX U2 XX U2 U2 U2
```

For the second argument of the fun.Majority() I needed to tell R to make use of the row index which was found at the first position of each row, that is, my.row[1]

Is there any other alternative to this procedure? I mean without having to create a new data frame with a column that should contain the index of each row.
Maybe when calling function(my.row) inside apply, there can be another way to pass to the function fun.Majority() the index of the row as well. (note that as I mentioned in the title, I would like to stay in the context of 'apply' function for my own reasons)

Thanks,
Valentin

Comment: You could use `sapply(1:nrow(test.df), function(row.idx){ call fun.Majority here using row.idx to select the current row of  test.df })`

Comment: I don't understand your function at all and what are you trying to do. Why are you looking for exact 2 matches of `U2` and exact two matches of `U1`? Why is that called "majority"? Non of your rows satisfy that condition btw. A simple test of `(rowSums(test.df == "U1") == 2) & (rowSums(test.df == "U2") == 2)` shows that. I think you should try to make your question a bit clearer and provide a clearer example with better explanation and clearer desired output. Your function just confuses me. And I don't think this whole procedure needs neither `apply` or creating a new data set.

Comment: @David, I agree the code is extremely complex for what it does and it's tricky to know what the OP wants at first glance.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I would wait for some clarifications, but it's your call.

Comment: he wants to know in test.df if there are 2 "U1" and 2 "U2" on each row on the first `4` columns, if so, he writes "U1" in a new column `Mj`, otherwise he writes the value of the corresponding row and fifth column of df.test in `Mj`. In any case, no need to write another dataframe!

Comment: I am sure it can be done in a vectorized approach as well (as the answer of @ColonelBeauvel), is just that I want to stick with the apply family functions. The suggestion of @digEmAll works very nice, as I have to keep my function (no matter how I name it...and how complex will get). This did the job `test.df$Mj2 <- sapply(1:nrow(test.df), function(row.idx) fun.Majority(test.df[row.idx, -5], test.df[row.idx, 5]))`